# The Cech--deRham complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-forms

I am absolutely stuck, reading Bott and Tu isomorphism of de Rham cohomology.  Please help. On page 92,

http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/botttu.pdf

Step 2. $r^{*}$ is injective.

$$ r(\omega)=D\phi^{'}=d\phi^{'}, 
~~~\delta \phi^{'}=0 $$

I think the claim that $ \delta \phi^{'}=0 $ is not correct and hence neither is the proof. Can someone check the proof. It starts from page 91.

Edit: Here is why I think the proof is not correct. 
Let's follow the proof from page 91 to 92 for two columns only. 
In the injective part, we argue that we can write  $\phi$ as a sum:

$$\phi=\phi^{'}+D\phi^{''}$$

where $\phi^{'}$ has only top component. This is shown on the previous page as follow. Let $\phi=(\alpha_0, \alpha_1)$ then by exactness there exists $\beta$ such that $\alpha-D\beta$ has only top component. Let's write this explicitly. 
We set $\beta=\phi^{''}=(\beta_0, 0)$ and $\delta\beta_{0}=\alpha_{1}$ to get the notation on page 92.

$$D\phi^{''}=D(\beta_{0}, 0) = (d\beta_0, \delta \beta_0)$$ and thus:

$$\phi^{'}=\phi-D\phi^{''}=(\alpha_0-d\beta_0, \alpha_1-\delta \beta_0)=(\alpha_0-d\beta_0, 0)$$

so $$\delta\phi^{'}= \delta(\alpha_0-d\beta_0)=\delta\alpha_{0}-d\alpha_1$$ and there is no reason why we should assume $\delta\alpha_0-d\alpha_1=0$.

Comment: Why do you think the claim is not correct?

Comment: I took a look and could not see an obvious reason why $\delta\phi'=0$. I noticed they used the fact again for the general proof a few pages later, again without justification.

Comment: I would guess downvotes are because people don't like questions that are not self-contained. You should add all relevant context to your question, instead of asking people to open a PDF and page through 100 pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To address the edit*: you're misunderstanding what they are doing. A generic element in the total complex $C^*(\mathfrak U)$ of $K^{**}$ is of the form $(a,b)$ with $a\in \Omega^*(U)\oplus \Omega^*(V)$ and $b\in \Omega^*(U\cap V)$.

The map $r^* : \Omega^*(M)\longrightarrow C^*(\mathfrak U)$ sends $\omega$ to $(a,0)$ where $a=(\omega\mid_U,\omega\mid_V)$. Take a closed form $\omega$, and asume that $r^*(\omega)=(a,0)$ is a boundary in $C^*(\mathfrak U)$. Then $(a,0) = D\varphi$ for some $\varphi$. Now $\varphi$ is an element of $C^*(\mathfrak U)$, and by the argument in the book, there is $\varphi'$ of the form $(\eta',0)$ so that $\varphi-\varphi'=D\nu$ in $C^*(\mathfrak U)$. Thus $(a,0) = D\varphi'$. Now $D\varphi'=D(\eta',0)=(d\eta',\delta \eta')$, and since this equals $(a,0)$, then
$$d\eta'=a$$
$$\delta \eta'=0$$

The first equation says that $\omega$ is the boundary of $\eta'$ on each $U,V$, the second says that $\eta'=(\eta_1,\eta_2) \in \Omega^*(U)\oplus \Omega^*(V)$ is a globally defined form, so $\omega$ is a boundary, as desired.

Comment: Actually then if we assume $D\phi=(a,0)$ $\delta\alpha_0-d\alpha_1=0$ has to be zero according even my own construction. Since it is the second term in $D\phi^{'}=D\phi=(a,0)$? right

Comment: Exactly. You don't have to assume it, it is given by the definition of $r^*$.

Comment: yeahhhhhhh! :).

Comment: would you see this?

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109142/cohomology-of-tensor-product-of-a-vector-space-with-a-double-complex

Answer (score 6):

The crucial step is that one can always replace a cochain in $K^{**}$ by one with one with last component zero.

To see that $r*$ is onto, take a cocycle in $K^{**}$. By the first remark, this is represented by a pair of forms $(\eta_1,\eta_2)$, and the cocycle condition means in the vertical direction, that each $\eta_i$ is closed, and second, that $\eta_1=\eta_2$ in $U\cap V$. Thus there is a global form $\omega$ that restricts to $(\eta_1,\eta_2)$.

To see that $r*$ is injective, take a global form $\omega$ and suppose the restrictions $(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ have trivial class in $\operatorname{Tot} K^{**}$, so this is of the form $D\varphi$ for some $\varphi$. By the first remark, one can assume $\varphi$ has zero last component. Now $r^*\omega$ **also** has zero last component --  it has $(q,0)$ component $r^*\omega$ and $(q-1,1)$ component $0$, and because $D\varphi=r^*\omega$, it follows that $\delta\varphi=0$, so $\varphi$ is a globally defined form. But we also have $d\varphi=r^*\omega$, so $\omega$ is exact.

---

Their proof can be phrased as follows. There is a double complex $C^{**}$ obtained by looking at the exact sequence of complexes as such a double complex:

$$ \Omega^*(M)\stackrel{r}\longrightarrow \Omega^*(U)\oplus \Omega^*(V) \longrightarrow \Omega^*(U\cap V)$$

This is a first quadrant cohomological double complex, and it has exact rows. Now there is induced a map $$r: \Omega^*(M)\to \operatorname{Tot}(K^{**})$$

as described by Bott and Tu. Now one checks the cone of $r$ is exactly the total complex of $C^{**}$, and because $C^{**}$ has exact rows -- by virtue of the exactness of the Mayer-Vietoris sequnce --- its total complex is acyclic. Because $\operatorname{cone}(r^*)$ is acyclic, it follows that $r$ is a quasi-isomorphism, as desired.

So, let us show that if a first quadrant cohomological complex $C^{**}$ has exact rows, then $\operatorname{Tot}(C^{**})$ is acyclic. Write $d'$ for the vertical differential and $d''$ for the horizontal one.

Consider a cocycle $c=(c_{0,q},c_{1,q-1},\ldots,c_{q,0})$. Then $d''c_{q,0}=0$. Because the rows are exact, there is $b_{q,0}$ such that $d''b_{q,0}=c_{q,0}$. Then $c'=c-Db$ where $b=(0,\ldots,0,b_{q,0})$ has last component $0$, and $Dc'=0$. Continue in this way: inductively assume you have killed the last $j$ components, so now $d''c_{q-j,j}=0$, so there is $b_{q-j,j}$ such that $d''b_{q-j,j}=c_{q-j,j}$. Inductively, we reach $c''$ with only the *top component* $(0,q)$ nonzero. But if $Dc''=0$, this means that $d''_{0,q}c''_{0,q}=0$, and since $d''$ is injective at $(0,*)$ because our complex has exact rows, it follows that $c''=0$. This is **exactly** what Bott and Tu are doing.

Comment: So Bott and Tu meant to apply the argument "we can assume the form to only have top component" to $D\phi$, rather than to $\phi$?

Comment: @ziggurism No. They mean what they said. $D\varphi$ has only top component by construction, because $r^*$ maps to the first column of $\operatorname{Tot}(K^{**})$, and one can assume $\varphi$ has only top component by their claim.

Comment: Hm ok so $\varphi\in K^{(q,0)}$ and therefore $D\varphi = d\varphi\pm\delta\varphi\in K^{(q+1,0)}\oplus K^{(q,1)}$ but since it equals $r^*\omega\in K^{(q+1,0)}$ we conclude the second component vanishes. Is that it?

Comment: @ziggurism Yes. ${}$

Comment: So did we actually need to make this argument about $\varphi$ having only top component? Seems like a red herring. Without it, we have $\varphi=\alpha+\beta\in K^{q,0}\oplus K^{q-1,1}$ and then $D\varphi=(d\pm\delta)(\alpha+\beta)=d\alpha + (\delta\alpha+d\beta) + \delta\beta \in K^{q+1,0}\oplus K^{q,1}\oplus K^{q-1,2}$. Then set it equal to $r^*\omega\in K^{q+1,0}$ and conclude that the components in $K^{q,1}$ and $K^{q-1,2}$ vanish.

Comment: @ziggurism That's different from what the authors are doing. You already know said components of $D\varphi$ vanish, but you want the last component of $\varphi$ to vanish, because then the vertical and horizontal differentials "don't mix". You're going back to your first comment, which we agreed was incorrect. You need to use one can kill all but the top component because you want to use the assembly lemma: if a first quadrant double complex has exact rows, its total complex is exact. That the Mayer-Vietoris sequence is exact implies $r^*$ is an isomorphism, so you better use it.

Comment: OK thanks for explaining, Pedro. I think I understand now. (Although of course I'm not OP. Hopefully OP likes your answer too).

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff would you see my edit above why I think the proof on page 91, 92 is not correct?

Comment: @alireza: Pedro's point is that it is not solely because $\phi'$ has only top component that $\delta \phi'=0$. You must also notice that it equals $r^*(\omega)$ which has only top component, forcing $\delta\phi'$ to vanish. I'm still a bit unclear whether we needed to ensure that $\phi'$ have only top component for this argument to go through though.